Base64 String from File Starts with 3 Bytes that Aren't Valid base64
I'm replicating a Python program in C#. The first thing that this program does is to load data from a binary file and base64 decode it. I've noticed that in both Python and C#, the file starts with 3 bytes that aren't valid base64 or even ASCII. Here's what it looks like in Python
b'\xec\xce\x16TFeIrTZDQKsiH54bCLkFLXRwHWEka2pYxtPfJplnECzJaMFcjnA...

The python base64 decoding method (base64.b64decode) doesn't seem to have a problem decoding this value, but the C# one does unless these 3 bytes are removed. Can someone explain what's going on here? Thanks.

The Python method will ignore invalid characters unless you pass validate=True.
